# Sum four by four rows on sql

Tags: sql

first time here. I am amateur on Sql and i need help from someone more experience I have this table:

```
x   DataYear    DataWeek    y       Lg                  CCLg
1   2011        39          13      6498,81826045676    0,00200036367828608
2   2011        40          1237    6506,60449729274    0,19011452140893
3   2011        41          4852    6514,39073412873    0,744812553932403
4   2011        42          9046    6522,17697096471    1,38696021899908
5   2011        43          4789    6529,96320780069    0,733388511941241
6   2011        44          7402    6537,74944463668    1,13219389373698
7   2011        45          6346    6545,53568147266    0,969515759873183
8   2011        46          6532    6553,32191830864    0,996746395404585
9   2011        47          6215    6561,10815514463    0,947248521597188
10  2011        48          7319    6568,89439198061    1,11419054155219
```

At the end in a new column at the first row I want to sum the first four numbers of y (13+1237+4852+9046)  column, at the second row the next four number of y (1237 + 4852 + 9046 + 4789)

Thanks Thanks Thank

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If column x contains data that you can order with, You can use FOLLOWING functions as below to get your required output. Also you can use the same logic with other ordering which is appropriate for your data.

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8e9304292423099705aad9d37c17503b)

```
SELECT *,
SUM(y) OVER (ORDER BY x ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 5 FOLLOWING),
SUM(y) OVER (ORDER BY x ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 2 FOLLOWING )
FROM your_table
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. Also If i want to sum the previous the current and two followings?

Comment: Hi @Skipper, please check my updated script. You can also put an up vote if it helped :)

Comment: How can I vote you... :) I am new here!!!!! And new on Sql..!

Comment: Just make a click on the UP arrow showing above the zero :) @Skipper

Answer (score 1):

Rows in a relational database don't have any order. To be able to talk about "the first four rows" you need something you can `ORDER BY`. Given your sample data I assume this is the column `x`.

What you are describing can be done using window functions with a "rolling window":

```
select x, datayear, dataweek, y, lg, cclg,
       sum(y) over (order by x rows between current row and 3 following) as sum_y
from the_table
order by x, datayear, dataweek;
```

[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0f37e1f744616f28ce50c07f12d5308e)

The demo contains an additional column that shows the values that have been included in the sum - the `array_agg()` function is Postgres specific, the window function is not.